# How can I get the data with select query with not writing all columns extenally and date formating is possible

Tags: sql-server

I have a stored procedure that fetches the data for some all registered users but I want the Date of birth to change in some format `MM/dd/yyyy`. I can do this with the `convert` function but how to fetch the record with select query? Do I need to write all vales separately or can I fetch it with simple select query and at the same time change the date format as well?

```
CREATE PROCEDURE GetAll
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT * FROM tbl_Regis
END

CREATE PROCEDURE GetAll
AS
BEGIN
   select Convert(varchar(20), DOB, 103) as DOB from tbl_RegisSadhak
END
```

Comment: I mean i need to select all 15 fields from the database but just to change a dateformate do i need to write all select fields externally in the select query? or any alternate exist

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should specify the columns you want and you have to apply the conversion on every column you want converted.

Comment: no other way it just for 1 field to foramt i need to specify 15 fields externally...

Comment: @NoviceToDotNet: either you use `*` to get **all** columns (as they are - no conversions applied), or then you have to specify the **list of columns** you want explicitly. No magic "other way", no.